# detached std::thread on esp32 arduino sometimes blocks, sometimes doesn't

Tags: c++, c++11, esp32

I have some code running on ESP32 microcontroller with arduino core,
In the `setup()` function I wish to have some code `threadPressureCalib` run independently in its own thread, so I do the following:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::thread>  sensorCalib;
void setup()
{
    sensorCalib.reset(new std::thread(threadPressureCalib));
    std::thread*  pc = sensorCalib.get();
    pc->detach();
}


 void loop()
{
...
}
```

Then, I define `threadPressureCalib()` as follows:

```
void threadPressureCalib() 
{
  float pressure=0;
  int count;

  for(timestarted = millis();(millis()-timestarted) < 10000;)
  { // THIS ONE BLOCKS SETUP() AND LOOP() CODE EXECUTION

      Serial.println("Doing things");

  }
  Serial.println("Doing other things");
  for (count=1; count<= 5;count++)
  { //THIS ONE DOES NOT BLOCK SETUP() and LOOP()
    float temp;
    while(!timer2.Delay(2000)); //Not sure if this is blocking anything
    do{
      temp = adc_pressure();
    }while(temp>104.0 || temp<70.0); //Catch errors 
    pressure += temp;

  }
  changeSetting(pressure/5.0);
  return;
  
}
```

**Problem:** During the first for loop, the `setup()` function's execution is stopped (as well as `loop()`)

During the second for loop, nothing is stopped and the rest of the code runs in parallel (as expected)

Why is it that the first half of this code blocks, and then the second half does not?

Sorry if the question is vague or improperly asked, my first q here.

Explanation of timer2 per request in comments:

timer2 is a custom timer class, `timer2.Delay(TIMEOUT)` stores timestamp the first time it's called and returns `false` on every subsequent call until the current time = TIMEOUT, then it returns `true` and resets itself

```
NonBlockDelay timer2;

 //time delay function (time in seconds to delay)
// Set iTimeout to current millis plus milliseconds to wait for  
/** 
 * Called with milliseconds to delay. 
 * Return true if timer expired 
 *  
 */  
//Borrowed from someone on StackOverflow... 

bool NonBlockDelay::Delay (unsigned long t)  
{  
  if(TimingActive)  
  {  
    if((millis() >iTimeout)){  
      TimingActive = 0;  
      return(1);  
    }  
    return(0);  
  }  
  iTimeout = millis() + t;  
  TimingActive = 1;  
  return(0);  
};  

// returns true if timer expired  
bool NonBlockDelay::Timeout (void)  
{  
  if(TimingActive){  
    if((millis() >iTimeout)){  
      TimingActive = 0;  
      iTimeout = 0;  
      return(1);  
    }  
  }  
  return(false);  
} 

// Returns the current timeout value in milliseconds 
unsigned long NonBlockDelay::Time(void)  
 {  
   return iTimeout;  
 }
```

Comment: Well your first loop seems to be a busy-loop spinning the CPU for 10 seconds so I guess that is why it blocks.

Comment: But in the second ```for()``` loop, the ```timer2.Delay()``` inside the ```while()``` makes that second for loop take the same 10 seconds, but that whole time nothing is being blocked. Even inside the while loop!

Comment: What is the type of timer2? I do not know what kind of implementation that Delay function holds or why it is converted to a boolean. Maybe it is implemented as something that yields CPU to other threads.

Comment: added explanation of timer2

Comment: So it is also basically a busy-loop, well then we are down to the first loop doing `Serial.println()` which seems a bit suspect.

Comment: I added a ```Serial.prinln()``` to the second loop and that one does not block either 

To be honest, I __want__ the first loop to block, but it's very scary that I don't know why its doing so. 
Maybe because in the first ```for()``` loop, the code is idling inside the ```for()``` loop's "condition", 
While in the second ```for()``` loop, the code is idling inside the loop's code?

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information here to tell you the answer but it seems that you have no idea what you are doing.

```
std::unique_ptr<std::thread>  sensorCalib;
void setup(){
      sensorCalib.reset(new std::thread(threadPressureCalib));
      std::thread*  pc = sensorCalib.get();
      pc->detach();
}
```

So here you store a new thread that executes `threadPressureCalib` then immediately detach it. **Once the thread is detached the instance `std::thread` no longer manages it.** So what's the point of even having `std::unique_ptr<std::thread>  sensorCalib;` in the first place if it literally does nothing? Do you realize that normally you need to `join` the thread if you wish to wait till it's completion? Could it be that you just start a bunch of instances of these `threadPressureCalib` - as you probably don't verify that they finished execution - and they interfere with each other?

Comment: Hi There, Thanks for your response. 
I borrowed the smart-pointer implementation and you are correct I have no idea why its there. 

I do wish to detatch the thread, I do NOT want the main handle or any other code to wait for ```threadPressureCalib```  to finish executing. 

There is only one instance of ```threadPressureCalib``` running after the setup code exits. I can verify this by the ```Serial.print()``` calls it's making.

My issue is why the first ```for()``` loop in ```threadPressureCalib``` blocks all the rest of my code, but the second ```for()``` loop does not

Comment: @ark02 you need to post what the functions/methods do. Otherwise we cannot know what they do thus we cannot tell you what is the issue. You can also debug it easily. Just print the value for pressure - so you can see the issue.

Comment: Happy to post more context, I just didn't want to clutter the post. Which functions/methods should I post more info about?

Comment: @ark02 see this guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example